# new tkinter window loses focus after mainloop ends

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using the following code to create a window after destroying another.

```
from tkinter import *
tk=Tk()
def destroy():
    tk.destroy()
tk.after(2000,destroy)
tk.mainloop()
tk=Tk()
tk.mainloop()
```

The window is created alright, but it loses focus. I tried `lift()` and `focus()` methods with no result.

Comment: Use `tk.focus_force()`

Comment: `tk = Tk()` is a really bad idea... Use a better name for your variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<tk.Tk>.focus_force()` to force the window to be focused.

So your modified code will look like this:

```py
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
def destroy():
    tk.destroy()

tk.after(2000, destroy)
tk.mainloop()

tk = Tk()
tk.focus_force()
tk.mainloop()
```

Although it is much better to reuse the window. Destroy all of the widgets on the window and reuse it instead of destroying and recreating it. Creating a window takes a lot of resources.

Also something else: the variable `tk` is usually used for something else so please don't use it for `tkinter` windows. Usually people use `root` or `window` for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Force the input focus to the widget using `focus_force()`. Just update you last part.

```
tk=Tk()
tk.focus_force()
tk.mainloop()
```

Also, You can make a Toplevel() which is basically just creating a new window over the root window.

```
from tkinter import *
tkk=Tk()
tkk.withdraw()
tk=Toplevel()
def destroy():
    tk.destroy()
    tkk.deiconify()
tk.after(2000,destroy)

tk.focus_force()
tkk.mainloop()
```

Comment: [Sujay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15801675/sujay) focus_force is great, thank you.

Comment: Welcome @SaikatChakraborty, No problem